# Why does Python/Django create duplicate files

Tags: python, django, file

I am new to Django and have gone through the tutorial. The example directory looks like this

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

mine is slightly different (still works)

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    __init__.pyc
    models.py
    models.py~
    models.pyc
    tests.py
    views.py
```

What do the extra file extensions mean? why are there multiple duplicate files?

The extensions added are .pyc and .py~

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pyc` files are [python compilation files](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/node43.html) - It contains byte code that the Python interpreter compiles from the source file.

So, once you run the application, `pyc` files are created automatically.

`py~` are temporary/backup files - It is created by the editor to save the previous versions of the file.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the explanation